# Call Matlab GUI variables in a loop

Tags: matlab, user-interface

For MATLAB GUI in the m-file, I want to call a set of variables. I have tagged the variables as axes1,axes2,axes3,.......axes125. How can I call it in a loop? Is it possible?

```
L = imread('white.jpg','jpg');
set(project.cantStop,'CurrentAxes',project.axes1);
set (imshow(L));
```

See the code

```
set(project.cantStop,'CurrentAxes',project.axes1);
```

I want to set it the same way for all 125 variables

Answer (score 0):

Use a cell array to store the axes' tags as strings and use them as the fieldnames to `handles` as shown below:

```
%// Cell arary of strings wih the axes's tags
axes_list = {'axes1','axes2','axes3'};

%// For demo on how to use the cell array, use it to choose the axes with
%// tag - `project.axes2`
axes(project.(axes_list{2}));
```

Thus, you can use a for-loop to loop through the axes for your case, like this -

```
for k = 1:numel(axes_list)
    set(project.cantStop,'CurrentAxes',project.(axes_list{k})); 
end
```

As an example to something similar to what you are trying to achieve with your sample codes, you can show a series of images on the axes. For the demo, let's suppose if you have a set of three images that you would like to show on three axes of the GUI.

```
%// List of image filenames as a cell array
files_list = {'p1.jpg','p2.jpg','p3.jpg'};

%// List of axes tags as a cell array of strings
axes_list = {'axes1','axes2','axes3'};

%// Show those three images on three different axes of the GUI 
for k = 1:numel(files_list)
    L = imread(files_list{k},'jpg');
    axes(project.(axes_list{k}));
    imshow(L);
end
```

Comment: suppose I have 125 axes. Do I have to declare the cell to store all 125 axe's tags? Will it look like this:  axes_list = {'axes1','axes2','axes3','axes4','axes5',........,'axes125'};

Comment: @MuAz Yes! Try this to get all those without the need to type those - `axes_list = strrep(strcat('axes',cellstr(num2str([1:125]','%1d'))),' ','')`. Let me know how it goes!